# Convert tab to fasta format in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have text (`infile-table.txt`) file with two columns separated by tab like this:

```
TRINITY_DN5561_c0_g1_i1 len=391 path=[369:0-390] [-1, 369, -2]  TTGGCTGGAATTCAAAAGCTTTCGATT
TRINITY_DN15396_c0_g1_i1 len=235 path=[213:0-234] [-1, 213, -2] CGAGCTTGGGTAAATGGGATCAAACTAGATTA
len=298 path=[1:0-297] [-1, 1, -2]  GCTGTGATTTCTGCCATCGGAGAGGGCACAGACGGC
```

I want to convert them like this:

```
>TRINITY_DN5561_c0_g1_i1 len=391 path=[369:0-390] [-1, 369, -2] 
TTGGCTGGAATTCAAAAGCTTTCGATT
>TRINITY_DN15396_c0_g1_i1 len=235 path=[213:0-234] [-1, 213, -2]    
CGAGCTTGGGTAAATGGGATCAAACTAGATTA
>len=298 path=[1:0-297] [-1, 1, -2] 
GCTGTGATTTCTGCCATCGGAGAGGGCACAGACGGC
```

command I tried and didn't work:

```
awk '{printf ">%s\n%s\n",$1,$2}' infile-table.txt > outfile.fasta
```

Comment: Why do YOU think it didn't work?

Comment: @ghoti Of course, I didn't know how to select `\t` feature within awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just missing "tab-separated" bit:

```
awk -F '\t' '{printf ">%s\n%s\n",$1,$2}' infile-table.txt
#...^^^^^^^
```

The awk program can be made a bit more terse, if you like: set the **output** field separator to a newline and:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\n' '{$1 = ">" $1} 1' infile-table.txt
```

When you alter the first field, awk will recreate $0 using the OFS, and the trailing "1" prints the record.

And, since you added the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) tag:

```
sed 's/^/>/;s/\t/\n/' infile-table.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use python! Create a file called "extract.py":

```
lines = open("infile-table.txt").readlines()

for line in lines:
    cols = line.split("\t")
    print(">"+cols[0]+"\n"+cols[1])
```

Then, run in terminal: "python extract.py".